# What is the difference in .embeddedframework.zip and .framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, unreal-engine4, embedded-framework

I am attempting to extend some functionality to a plugin designed for use in Unreal Engine 4. Using the documentation available and reviewing the solution I've encountered something I do not understand and cannot figure out a way to research it.

In this plugin, the original developer has 2 different files *.embeddedframework.zip, in each of these files there are some binary files, module maps, and *.h files. These *.h files are able to include iOS modules.

I have been able to create .framework builds using Xcode, unfortunately, the do not seem to contain the same format as the *.embeddedframework.zip file.

I apologize for the vague question; I'm new to iOS and I'm quite stumped, any leads whatsoever would be appreciated! (code available on request but it's really quite boilerplate)

Answer (score 1):

`YourFramework.embeddedframework.zip` is just a zip archive of the Xcode products that takes the following form:

```
YourFramework.embeddedframework.zip
  > YourFramework.embeddedframework/
    > YourFramework.framework/
```

After you link it and build, you can verify that the unzipping worked by checking here:
`/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.17/Engine/Intermediate/UnzippedFrameworks/`